# Spotfire - Calculate Difference between two values in a graph create by date

Tags: spotfire

I am shwoing a data of pressure in a graph by date which can selected from the filter ( days, months, years)

I would like to calculate the difference between the twos extremum data in the plot  [ last Value-  first Value] ( when user change a filter i show the new calculation as the graph will change )

here my custome expression but i not working properly ( Date is X axis values ) Level Pressure Y axis :

Abs(if([Property Name]="LevelPressure",[Average Reading])) - sum(if([Property Name]="LevelPressure",[Average Reading])) over (PreviousPeriod([Date]))

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Comment: thanks philip - here the code i tried : Abs(if([Property Name]="PressureLevel",[Average Reading])) 
    - sum(if([Property Name]="PressureLevel",[Average Reading])) 
    over (PreviousPeriod([Generated At]))  where Generated refer my respective dates